# Can the Canon 5D Mark II be set to save exposure settings on auto power off?

Tags: canon, manual-mode, canon-5d-mark-ii, camera-settings

I usually use my 5D mark II in manual mode, with auto power off enabled, but every time it auto powers off, my exposure settings (shutter speed, aperture, iso) are lost. It seems like there should be a setting for those to be saved and restored.

It's very annoying as a lot of times I will dial in an exposure while hiking or out somewhere, and then when I go to take a picture a few minutes later my settings are lost and I take something way over exposed and miss whatever moment I was trying to capture.

Is there a setting I'm missing, or some kind of alternate firmware which will do this? It seems like something Canon should have thought of, but I haven't been able to find any information elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried the same thing on my 5DmkII and it works fine for me: the aperture, shutter speed, ISO and WB I set in M mode are still there when the camera's auto-powered off and been re-awoken. I'm on firmware 2.0.8, and I have auto power-off set to 1 minute.

Not sure if it's helpful to mention, but what you've described is exactly what I get if I'm in one of the custom modes (C1, C2, C3). That's by design though and worked exactly the same on my 40D. It's definitely not correct behaviour in M mode though: I wonder how the camera decides which settings it ought to revert to.

Comment: Just checked on mine, with same results...

Comment: Ahh ok. I am using a custom mode I setup from M, so that would be why. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! If you could mark my answer as accepted that's be grand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a firmware or model related problem, but on my Mark IV you can do this by going tab 4 in Set Up, "Custom Shooting Modes (C1-C3)" and enabling "Auto Update Set.". You've probably figured this out by now.

Answer (score -2):

There doesn't appear to be anything in the manual to change this. The only suggestion I could give is to assign the settings you want to one of the Custom functions, which should 'remember' them even after powering off.

Or of course, you could just switch to Nikon ;)

Comment: Tempted to -1 for the Nikon quip: come on, let's keep those silly unhelpful kind of comments off this site please.

Comment: Ditto, filthy Nikon users ;)